# Disabling select2 options based on selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to do something very similar to this fiddle, but rather than disable the other selections in the same group as which is selected, I want to disable all the options which are NOT in the same group as the one selected...therefore forcing the user to select another option from the same group.

However, even if I simply copy the code from the fiddle, it gives me an error:

https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/hpkqxto6/

```
   <select multiple style="width: 300px">
      <option groupid="a" value="A_AK">Alaska</option>
      <option groupId="b" value="B_HI">Hawaii</option>
      <option groupid="c" value="C_CA">California</option>
      <option groupid="a" value="D_NV">Nevada</option>
      <option groupid="b" value="A_OR">Oregon</option>
      <option groupid="c" value="B_WA">Washington</option>
      <option groupid="a" value="C_AZ">Arizona</option>
      <option groupid="b" value="D_CO">Colorado</option>
      <option groupid="c" value="A_ID">Idaho</option>
      <option groupid="a" value="B_MT">Montana</option>
      <option groupid="b" value="C_NE">Nebraska</option>
      <option groupid="c" value="D_NM">New Mexico</option>
      <option groupid="a" value="A_ND">North Dakota</option>
      <option groupid="b" value="B_UT">Utah</option>
      <option groupid="c" value="C_WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
```

```
         $(function() {
       $('select').select2({
         allowClear: true,
         placeholder: "Pick a State"
       });
    
       //Select2 Event handler for selecting an item
       $('select').on("select2:selecting", function(evt, f, g) {
         disableSel2Group(evt, this, true);
       });
    
       // Select2 Event handler for unselecting an item
       $('select').on("select2:unselecting", function(evt) {
         disableSel2Group(evt, this, false);
       });
     });
    
    
     // At some point during the select2 instantation it created the 
     // data object it needs with the source select option.
     // This function, called by the events above to set the current status for the
     // group for which the selected option belongs.
     function disableSel2Group(evt, target, disabled) {
       // Found a note in the Select2 formums on how to get the item to be selected
    
       var selId = evt.params.args.data.id;
       var group = $("option[value='" + selId + "']").attr("groupid");
    
       var aaList = $("option", target);
       $.each(aaList, function(idx, item) {
         var data = $(item).data("data");
    
         var itemGroupId = $("option[value='" + data.id + "']").attr("groupid");
         if (itemGroupId == group && data.id != selId) {
           data.disabled = disabled;
         }
       })
     }
```

The idea being that when an option is selected in a select2 dropdown, it then disables other options. However, even if I simply recreate this code, I get an error (cannot read property 'id' of undefined) which triggers on the line:

```
    var group = $("option[value='" + selId + "']").attr("groupid");
```

Can anyone help fix the error, and then help me with my main intention of disabling all other groups? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `evt.params.args.data.element` this will give you option tag html then using this you can get the `groupid` value and compare it with all options attr if not same disabled that option.

Now , instead of `unselecting` use `unselect` because here you need to enable all options when select-box doesn't have any value selected . So , inside your function get `select2('data').length` and if length is `0` then only enabled all options.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: "Pick a State"

  });

  $('select').on("select2:selecting", function(evt, f, g) {
    disableSel2Group(evt, this, true);
  });

  $('select').on("select2:unselect", function(evt) {
    disableSel2Group(undefined, undefined, false);
  });

})



function disableSel2Group(evt, target, disabled) {
  //check if disabled true
  if (disabled) {
    //get option
    var selId = evt.params.args.data.element;
    var group = $(selId).attr('groupid') //groupid 

    var aaList = $("option", target);
    $.each(aaList, function(idx, item) {
      var other_groups = $(item).attr("groupid"); //get option groupid
      var data = $(item).data("select2-id"); //get option selct2id
      //if not same
      if (group != other_groups) {
        $("select option[data-select2-id =" + data + "]").prop("disabled", true); //disable that option

      }
    })
  } else {
    var count = $('select').select2('data').length //checcking slected data count
    console.log(count)
    //if 0 
    if (count == 0) {
      $("select option").prop("disabled", false); //enable all options
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select multiple style="width: 300px">

  <option groupid="a" value="A_AK">Alaska</option>

  <option groupid="b" value="B_HI">Hawaii</option>

  <option groupid="c" value="C_CA">California</option>

  <option groupid="a" value="D_NV">Nevada</option>

  <option groupid="b" value="A_OR">Oregon</option>

  <option groupid="c" value="B_WA">Washington</option>

  <option groupid="a" value="C_AZ">Arizona</option>

  <option groupid="b" value="D_CO">Colorado</option>

  <option groupid="c" value="A_ID">Idaho</option>

  <option groupid="a" value="B_MT">Montana</option>

  <option groupid="b" value="C_NE">Nebraska</option>

  <option groupid="c" value="D_NM">New Mexico</option>

  <option groupid="a" value="A_ND">North Dakota</option>

  <option groupid="b" value="B_UT">Utah</option>

  <option groupid="c" value="C_WY">Wyoming</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Hi Swati - thanks for taking a look for me. I'm following everything you've done. However, when console.log testing, the code is getting all the way into the if (group != other_groups) condition, but the disabling does not actually happen. I feel it's so close! Any ideas?

Comment: do console.log(data) see if it has any value or not because above code is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks - I think I've got something else conflicting with it preventing the disabling. I'll just have to keep on exploring, but thank you for your help!